# Python String Format args vs kwargs

Tags: python, string, class, format, arguments

Of the 2 classes below, Guitarist_1 and Guitarist_2, which one's object representation function's string format is most pythonic; accepted? I prefer Guitarist_1's because, I do not have to list out; order the properties in any particular way.

```
[Guitarist_1] Hendrix, Jimi (11/27/1942)
[Guitarist_2] Hendrix, Jimi (11/27/1942)
```

Guitarist.py

```
import re

class Guitarist(object):
    CLASS_NAME_RE = r'([A-Z][\w\d_]+)\'>$'
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, dob):
        self.fname, self.lname, self.dob = fname, lname, dob
    def className(self):
        return re.search(self.CLASS_NAME_RE, str(type(self))).group(1)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{}]'.format(self.className())

class Guitarist_1(Guitarist):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, dob):
        Guitarist.__init__(self, fname, lname, dob)
    def __repr__(self):
        return Guitarist.__repr__(self) + ' {lname}, {fname} ({dob})'\
        .format(**self.__dict__)


class Guitarist_2(Guitarist):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, dob):
        Guitarist.__init__(self, fname, lname, dob)
    def __repr__(self):
        return Guitarist.__repr__(self) + ' {}, {} ({})'\
        .format(self.lname, self.fname, self.dob)

print Guitarist_1('Jimi', 'Hendrix', '11/27/1942')
print Guitarist_2('Jimi', 'Hendrix', '11/27/1942')
```

Comment: In case of Guitarist_2 you could call `format` with unpacked list (which makes it about the same as Guitarist_1). Format string is for ordering stuff, then.

Comment: This question might find a better home on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FYI: `className` can be simplified to `return self.__class__.__name__`.  (Also, the `__init__`s in the derived classes are unnecessary if all they do is pass their arguments to the superclass's `__init__`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order is not important a simplified and very versatile version would be:

```
class Guitarist(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{0}('{1}')>".format(self.__class__.__name__, 
                                     "', '".join(self.__dict__.values()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Guitarist(fname='Jimi', lname='Hendrix', dob='11/27/1942'))
```

---

```
<Guitarist('Jimi', 'Hendrix', '11/27/1942')>
```